# open all links - verify some condition

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenide

I need to open all links from a page at a specific URL. If the link opens I need to check the page content and verify it does not contain specific text.

I used Selenide which is built on selenium, and tried the following:

```
String[] links = null;
int linksCount = 0;
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Resources/chromedriver1.exe");
     WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(new ChromeDriver());   
     driver= WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver();
    open("myURL");
    List<WebElement> linksize =      WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().findElements(By.tagName("a")); 
    linksCount = linksize.size();
    out.println("Total no of links Available: "+linksCount);
    links= new String[linksCount];
    out.println("List of links Available: ");  
    // print all the links from webpage 
    for(int i=0;i<linksCount;i++)
    {
    links[i] = linksize.get(i).getAttribute("href");
    System.out.println(linksize.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
    } 
    // navigate to each Link on the webpage
    for(int i=0;i<linksCount;i++)
    {
        if(links[i] != null)
            {
                if(!links[i].contains("javascript"))
                {
                    System.out.println(links[i]);
                    driver.navigate().to(links[i]);
                    Selenide.sleep(7);
                    WebElement error = $(Selectors.byText("no information!")); 
                    $(error).shouldNotBe(visible)
                    .shouldNotBe(text("information!"));
                }
            }

    }
```

I used the same solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898567/how-to-click-on-all-links-in-web-page). but I have this exception while checking:

> unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32603,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}
>     (Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.87)
>
> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32603,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}
>     (Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.87)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 4 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.50.1', revision: 'd7fc91b', time: '2016-01-29 19:04:49'

I used this chrome driver version from [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.9/)

What could be generating this error?

Comment: One of the href is most certainly not a link.

Answer (score 1):

From the error log you posted, its clear that "Cannot navigate to invalid URL". Provide a valid url and check - Thanks

Comment: I am exclude any url == null or emptyor contaiing (javascript) so what are the invalid urls?

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly this is failing long before you loop through your links.

The following line [will try to load](http://selenide.org/javadoc/3.4/com/codeborne/selenide/Selenide.html#open(java.lang.String)) what is clearly not a valid URL, which completely explains the error you got.

```
open("myURL");
```

Presumably you meant to pass in a variable named `myURL`?

Comment: Your code is wrong, `"myURL"` is not a valid URL. As I said, you probably meant to pass the value of a variable, which may evaluate to "vanilla.sa", though you didn't tell us that.